# Getting error while importing a python script as module

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have written below Python code and trying to use as a module by importing it from python shell but its throwing error.

```
def break_words(stuff):

"""This function will break up words fro us."""
    words = stuff.split('')
    return words

def sort_words(words):
"""sort the words."""
    return sorted(words)

def print_first_word(words):
 """Prints the first word after popping it off."""
    word=words.pop(0)
    print word

def print_last_word(words):
"""print the last word after poppomg it off."""
    word=words.pop(-1)
    print word

def sort_sentence(sentence):
    """Takes a full sentence and return the sorted word."""
    words= break_words(sentence)
    return sort_words(words)

def print_first_and_last(sentence):
    """Prints the first and last word of the sentences."""
    words = sort_sentence(sentence)
    print_first_word(words)
    print_last_word(words)
```

while I am importing it from the python shell:-

```
>>> import Breaking_code

Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
    import Breaking_code
ImportError: No module named Breaking_code
```

My aim is to use it as a module like below

```
sentence = "All good things come to those who wait."
words = Breaking_code.break_words(sentence)
output:- ['All', 'good', 'things', 'come', 'to', 'those', 'who', 'wait.']
```

Comment: It clearly says that python couldn't find the module Breaking_code. Either you are importing a different library or that file is in different location.

Comment: You need to add the module to your python PATH

Comment: Show us the module's filename.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok You have written a module in some directory that you want to import in shell.But the scope of your module is only limited to the directory in which the module is.To import the module in your shell

There are two options

1.Add the directory where your module is present in system environment variables.You can do this by code as well

```
import sys
sys.path.append("your\\ directory\\path here")
import breaking_code
```

2.just do quick directory changes

```
import os
os.chdir("your\\ directory\\path here") #changing current working directory
import breaking_code
```

Comment: I used the second method after restarting the python shell and it worked.Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

Breaking_Code.py is most likely not in the folder that the Python shell is in. If it is try just importing one function with

From breaking_code import sort_words

Comment: If it were in that directory, the import wouldn't be failing in the first place...